# How To Get Support For Ruby Prof Features In Ruby 2.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, performance-testing

I am currently running ruby 2.2.2 and rails 4.2 and when I include 'rails-perftest' and 'ruby-prof' in the gemfile I get the following output.

```
wall_time: 7 ms
memory: unsupported
objects: unsupported
gc_runs: 0
gc_time: 0 ms
```

Is there any way to see the memory and objects outputs or is this completely impossible with ruby 2.2.2?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to get this working? I'm kinda stuck on the same problem.

Comment: No, but I added an answer with explanation as to why.

Comment: Thanks. I got to the same conclusion today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as of right now, it is not possible to get those features working, and here is why:

The 'rails-perftest' gem depends on the 'ruby-prof' gem and according to the developer of the 'ruby-prof' gem stated that this was due to the 'rails-perftest' gem containing incorrect assumptions about how certain methods are used(seen here: https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof/issues/165). Issues have been raised on the 'rails-perftest' github repo, but I haven't seen too much progress recently.

Essentially the issue is with the 'rails-perftest' gem itself, and this issue can't be fixed until the gem is.